# I need to get the data from the multiple tables and I want to display that in the report form without repeating the primary key values

Tags: sql, database

```
empID   Hobbies    Salary
1   Cricket     100
1   Walleyball   100
1   Golf        100
2   Cricket     200
2   Golf        200
```

I need to get the data from the multiple tables and I want to display that in the report form without repeating the primary key values.. in the above table it should not display empID for every hobby and I need to have the total of salary at the end of the report.

How to overcome such problem

Comment: You say 'multiple tables' but only show the one

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking, this is not something you do in SQl, it is something you do in grouping in the report builder.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like this?:

```
empID   Hobbies    Salary
1       Cricket     
        Walleyball   
        Golf       300
2       Cricket     
        Golf       400
```

In five rows like that, or two rows like this:

```
empID   Hobbies                         Salary
1       Cricket, Walleyball, Golf       300
2       Cricket, Golf                   400
```

And which database system?

Comment: I think he wants your first example and as posted above, that's done in the reporting component, not the SQL component.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `empID`, SUM(`Salary`) AS `total_salary` FROM yourtable GROUP BY `empID`;
```

http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-group-by-sql-tutorial/

http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-aggregate-functions-sql-tutorial/